# SQL to calculate the status of a task using todays date

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I go about writing a SQL statement which uses today's date and calculates the status of a task.

I think this should return:

```
1 = complete task (status = completed)
2 = pending task (in the future and not status=completed) 
3 = overdue task (in the past and set to pending)
```

Table SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks` (
  `task_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `task_status` enum('pending','approved','complete','cancelled') NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something in these lines:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN task_status = 'complete' THEN 'Complete Task'
        WHEN status != 'complete' AND task_date > NOW() THEN 'Pending Task'
        WHEN status = 'pending' AND task_date < NOW() THEN 'Overdue Task'
FROM 
    tasks
```

`NOW()` needs to be replaced with MySQL equivalent, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If this is merely about extending the predefined set of statuses with the dynamically calculated `'overdue'` status, a CASE expression with just one condition should be enough:

```
SELECT
  ...
  CASE
    WHEN task_status = 'pending' AND task_date > CURDATE()
    THEN 'overdue'
    ELSE task_status
  END AS task_status,
  ...
FROM tasks
WHERE
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following:

```
SELECT task_id, task_date, 
  CASE 
    WHEN task_status = 'complete' THEN 'completed task'
    WHEN task_status != 'complete' AND task_date > CURDATE() THEN 'pending task'
    WHEN 
      (task_status != 'complete' AND task_date <= CURDATE()) 
      OR (task_status = 'pending') THEN 'pending task'
  END AS task_status_str
FROM 
  tasks
```